# POST method not supported Spring MVC - tacoCloud spring in action

Tags: java, spring

Hi I was following spring in Action 5tth edition book where in chapter two it says to add a OrderController which will have post and get mapping but whenever I try to hit the URL it gives me `"There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported"` error

I've tried searching over the stackoverflow but couldn't get any helpful link.

this is my **OrderForm.html**

```
    <h1>Order your taco creations!</h1>
    <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.jpg}"/>
    <a id="another" th:href="@{/design}">Design another taco</a><br/>
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}">
        <span class="validationError">
            Please correct the problems below and resubmit.
        </span>
    </div>
    <h3>Deliver my taco masterpieces to...</h3>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input th:field="*{name}" type="text"/>
    <br/> <label for="street">Street address: </label>
    <input th:field="*{street}" type="text"/>
    <br/> <label for="city">City: </label>
```

and here is my **OrderController.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
        System.out.println("sdsdsd");
        return "orderForm";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(Order order) {
        log.info("Order submitted: " + order);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the whole form html? Whats the value of the `th:action` attribute of your form?

Answer (score 0):

If spring security is enable you have to disable crsf protection ( if this is a possible option for your project)

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       super.configure(http);
       http.csrf().disable();          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the configuration class(annotated with `@Configuration`) that
`extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
and overrides `void configure(HttpSecurity http)`
and there provide some methods to http object.
For example:

```
http.
    csrf.disable()
    .antMatchers(/*urls that you permit to all*/).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

and others.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/